# ASP.NET MVC session alternative for a load balanced environment

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing, stateserver

Considering an architecture with multiple web servers (IIS) behind a load balancer, how can I decide what the best options are for keeping session information?

As I was told, the load balancer could be configured to use `sticky sessions`, but this doesn't seem to be an option due to constraints established by other applications running on the affected systems. Looking into that matter I usually end up with `State Server` as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Now what I don't understand is why I should use a single (?) State Server to keep hold of the session information from multiple web server systems - doesn't that render the whole load balancing approach useless? Or is the actual influence on the overall performance so insignificant that it can be ignored?

I can see that having such a server is a working solution, but I wonder if that actually is a good one. Would there be any other realistic options?

In general, I'd prefer to just enable `sticky sessions` on the load balancer as I can't see why that would be a problem considering the overall performance of the applications being hosted, but I'm also not very experienced in that matter.